# How to compute operation between tensor in custom Layer with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have my custom Layer named FinalLayer, I receive two tensor:
First tensor (named with shape :(None,128)
Second tensor with shape: (None,10,10,128)

That's my code

```
class FinalLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, input_dim):
        super(FinalLayer, self).__init__()
        self.total = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.zeros(input_dim), trainable=False)
        self.result = np.zeros([10,10])
        print(self.total)

    def call(self, inputs):
        #Convert KerasTensor to Tensor
        in1=inputs[0]
        in2=inputs[1]
        #in1=tf.convert_to_tensor(inputs[0])
        #in2=tf.convert_to_tensor(inputs[1])
        for i in range(10):
            for j in range(10):
                 print(i,j)
                 tensor_sub = tf.math.reduce_sum(  tf.math.abs(tf.subtract(in1[0,i,j,:],in2[0,:])) )
                 print(tensor_sub)
                 self.total[i,j]= tensor_sub
             
        
        return result
```

I try to measure distance between (None,128) vector and each of vector in the tensor (None,10,10,128),
For exemple, I extract from (None,10,10,128) a tensor of (None,0,0,128) and I want to compare it to the vector of shape (None,128).
I repeat it 100 times for all vector of (None,10,10,128) tensor.

That's the error I have obtained.

```
Tensor("final_layer_2/Sum:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-4f1174b2a603> in <module>()
     16 print(x2_vector_final)
     17 Merge_output=FinalLayer((10,10))
---> 18 print(Merge_output([x1,x2_vector_final]))
     19 
     20 #model_englobe=Model([image_original,Crop_image],output=output)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    668       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    669         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 670           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    671         else:
    672           raise

TypeError: in user code:

    <ipython-input-15-f801b666c04b>:19 call  *
        self.total[i,j]= tensor_sub

    TypeError: 'ResourceVariable' object does not support item assignment
```

I make  print(in1[0,i,j,:]) and  print(in2[0,:]) in the for loop:

```
Tensor("final_layer_5/strided_slice_152:0", shape=(128,), dtype=float32)
Tensor("final_layer_5/strided_slice_153:0", shape=(128,), dtype=float32)
```

Thank you

Comment: did u try self.total[i,j].assign(tensor_sub) ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't loop over tensors this is incredibly inefficient, exploit their broadcastability.

```py
import tensorflow as tf


class FinalLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def call(self, fst, snd):
        # broadcast second tensor
        # snd.shape = (batch, 1, 1, 6)
        snd = snd[:, None, None]
        # compare
        return tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.abs(fst - snd), 3)


# I reduced the dimensions for illustration
a = tf.random.normal([5, 4, 4, 6])
b = tf.random.normal([5, 6])

fl = FinalLayer()

fl(a, b).shape
# TensorShape([5, 4, 4])

fl(a, b)
# <tf.Tensor: shape=(5, 4, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=
# array([[[ 6.9481993,  6.0859094,  8.493639 ,  4.8121705],
#         [12.532196 ,  9.093214 ,  6.4541783,  7.6398764],
#         [ 4.623854 ,  7.629319 ,  7.389118 ,  4.885375 ],
#         [ 5.8578954,  9.007304 ,  7.7308807,  6.624958 ]],
# ...
```